# Is non-atomic value SELECT specific to SQL Server or it is possible in other DBMS-es?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, oracle, atomic

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278884/is-a-half-written-values-reading-prevented-when-select-with-nolock-hint/4283096#4283096) to my question [Is a half-written values reading prevented when SELECT WITH (NOLOCK) hint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278884/is-a-half-written-values-reading-prevented-when-select-with-nolock-hint) cites a script illustrating catching non-atomic reads (SELECTs) of partly-updated values in SQL Server.

Is such non-atomic  (partly updated, inserted, deleted) value reading problem specific to SQL Server?
Is it possible in other DBMS-es?

Update:
Not long time ago I believed that READ UNCOMMITTED transaction isolation level (also achieved through WITH(NOLOCK) hint in SQL Server) permitted reading (from other transactions) the uncommitted (or committed, if not yet changed) values but not partly modified (partly updated, partly inserted, partly deleted) values.

Update2:
The first two answers deviated the discussion to attacking READ UNCOMMITTED (isolation level ) phenomena specified by ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specifications.
This question is not about this.
Is non-atomicity of a value (not row!) is compliant with READ UNCOMMITTED and dirty read at all?

I believed that READ UNCOMMITTED did imply reading of uncommitted rows in their entirety but not partly modified values.

Does the definition of "dirty read" include possibility of value modification non-atomicity?

Is it a bug or by design?
or by ANSI SQL92  definition of "dirty read"?  I believed that "dirty read" did include atomic reading uncommitted rows but non-atomically modified values...

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible in other DBMS-es?

As far as I know the only other databases that allow READ UNCOMMITTED are DB2, Informix and MySQL when using a non-transactional engine.

Comment: Ingres used to allow it as well

Comment: The question was not about READ UNCOMMITTED. SQL Server has atomic value modifications for value sizes fitted in a page but non-atomic for LOBs (large objects more than 8K). The question is not about atomicity of UPDATE or INSERT or even atomicity of transaction but about atomicity of a value modification. One statement may have a few value modifications and one transaction can have multiple UPDATE, INSERT statements

Answer (score 1):

All hell would break loose if atomic statements were in fact not atomic.
I can answer this for MSSQL - all single statements are atomic, "dirty reads" refers to the 
possibility of reading a "phantom row" that might not exist after TX is committed/rolled back.

Comment: Exactly, my concern. If SQL Server does not assure atomicity of LOB reading from another transaction, what would assure its atomicity, then, in the same tx during, for example, parallel processing?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between Atomicity and READ COMMITTED if the implementation of the latter relies on locking.

Consider transactions A and B. Transaction A is a single SELECT for all records with a status of 'pending' (perhaps a full scan on a very large table so it takes several minutes).

```
At 3:01 transaction A reads record R1 in the database and sees its status is 'New' so doesn't return it or lock it.
At 3:02 transaction B updates record R1 from 'New' to 'Pending' and record R2000 from 'New' to 'Pending' (single statement)
At 3:03 transaction B commits
At 3:04 transaction A reads record R2000, sees it is 'Pending' and committed and returns it (and locks it).
```

In this situation, the select in transaction A has only seen part of Transaction B, violating atomicity. Technically though, the select has only returned committed records.

Databases relying on locking reads suffer from this problem because the only solution would be to lock the entirety of the table(s) being read so no-one can update any records in any of them. This would make it impractical for any concurrent activity.

In practice, most OLTP applications have very quick transactions operating on very small data volumes (relative to the database size), and concurrent operations tend to hit different 'slices' of data so the situation occurs very rarely. Even if it does happen, it doesn't necessarily result in a noticeable problem and even when it does they are very hard to reproduce and fixing them would require a whole new architecture. In short, despite being a theoretical problem, in practice it often isn't worth worrying about.

That said, an architect should be aware of the potential issue, be able to assess the risk for a particular application and determine alternatives.

That's one reason why [SQL Server added non-locking consistent reads in 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189050.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Database theory requires that in all isolation levels, the individual UPDATE or INSERT statements are atomic. Their intermediate results should not be visible to read uncommitted transactions. This has been stated in a paper by a group of well-known database experts. http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=69541

However, as read uncommitted results are not considered transactionally consistent by definition, it is possible that implementations may contain bugs that result in part-updated row sets to be returned and these bugs have not been noticed in tests because of the difficulty to determine the validity of the returned result sets.

Comment: Is it bug? Ppl argue that READ UNCOMMITTED implies non-atomic value modification http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/7eecddb8-b633-49e6-93ad-6a3222c80753 Well, the question really was about state-of-the-art amongst current implementations

Comment: Had a quick look. They seem to conflate NO LOCK and READ UNCOMMITTED. NOLOCK is an implementation-specific term refering to physical locks, while READ UNCOMMITTED is a theoretical term which means "read uncommitted actions by other connections", provided each "action" is a complete action. Therefore you were right to expect a consistent behaviour with READ UNCOMMITTED, but this cannot be achieved with the NOLOCK physical lock mode.